# Integración de varios Layout en Kivy

Tags: python, android-layout, kivy

Estoy buscando la siguiente funcionalidad en mi app.
Sea la siguiente pantalla de inicio:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Si le doy al botón "Hacer tanda de preguntas quiero que me pase al siguiente layaout:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Y si le doy al botón "Tiempo para nuevas preguntas" quiero que me pase a otro Layaout:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el archivo main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty

Builder.load_file('design.kv')


class MyWidget(BoxLayout):
    score = NumericProperty()

    def __init__(self):
        super(MyWidget, self).__init__()

    def showquestion(self):
        with open("question.txt", "r") as f:
            filetext = f.read()
            self.ids['label1'].text = filetext

    def showanswer(self):
        with open("answer.txt", "r") as f:
            filetext = f.read()
            self.ids['label2'].text = filetext

    def showTUQ(self):
        with open("TUQ.txt", "r") as f:
            filetext = f.read()
            self.ids['label4'].text = filetext


class myApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyWidget()

    def on_pause(self):
        return True

    def on_resume(self):
        pass


if __name__ in ('__main__', '__android__'):
    myApp().run()
```

design.kv:

```
<MyWidget>:
    size: root.size
    orientation: 'vertical'
    padding: 20
    spacing: 0

    #label1 muestra la pregunta
    Label:
        id: label1
        color: 1,0,1,1
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: 191/255.0, 144/255.0, 63/255.0, 1
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos

    #label2 muestra la respuesta
    Label:
        id: label2
        color: 1,0,1,1
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba:  110/255.0, 191/255.0, 63/255.0, 1
            Rectangle:
                pos:self.pos
                size: self.size

    Label:
        id: label3
        color: 1,0,1,1
        text: str(root.score)
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: 74/255.0, 25/255.0, 44/255.0, 1
            Rectangle:
                pos:self.pos
                size: self.size

    #label4 muestra el tiempo hasta las preguntas
    Label:
        id: label4
        color: 1,0,1,1
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: 33/255.0, 127/255.0, 190/255.0, 1
            Rectangle:
                pos:self.pos
                size: self.size

    BoxLayout:
        padding: 0,10,0,0
        spacing: 10
        size_hint:1, 0.25
        orientation: 'horizontal'
        Button:
            id: button1
            text: "Mostrar respuesta"
            on_release: root.showanswer()
        Button:
            id: button2
            text: "Pregunta Acertada"
            on_release: root.score += 10

        Button:
            id: button3
            text: "Pregunta Fallada"
            on_release: root.score -= 5
        Button:
            id: button4
            text: "Mostrar pregunta"
            on_release: root.showTUQ()

            # Botones de presentación

    BoxLayout:
        padding: 0,10,0,0
        spacing: 10
        size_hint:1, 0.25
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Button:
            id: button5
            text: "Tiempo para nuevas pregutnas"
            on_release: 
        Button:
            id: button6
            text: "Hacer tanda de preguntas"
            on_release:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para hacer lo que quieres lo lógico es usar [`ScreenManager`](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.screenmanager.html). Se trata de un Widget que permite manejar varias vistas en tu app y cambiar fácilmente de unas a otras. En la documentación viene un pequeño ejemplo de su funcionamiento. Tu código podría ser algo así:

**main.py:**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

Builder.load_file('design.kv')


class MyScreenManager(ScreenManager):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyScreenManager, self).__init__()


class VentanaMenu(Screen):
    pass


class VentanaNuevas(Screen):
    def showTUQ(self):
        with open("TUQ.txt", "r") as f:
            filetext = f.read()
            self.ids['label4'].text = filetext


class VentanaTanda(Screen):
    score = NumericProperty()

    def showquestion(self):
        with open("question.txt", "r") as f:
            filetext = f.read()
            self.ids['label1'].text = filetext

    def showanswer(self):
        with open("answer.txt", "r") as f:
            filetext = f.read()
            self.ids['label2'].text = filetext


class myApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyScreenManager()

    def on_pause(self):
        return True

    def on_resume(self):
        pass


if __name__ in ('__main__', '__android__'):
    myApp().run()
```

**design.kv:**

```
#:import WipeTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.WipeTransition


<MyScreenManager>:
    transition: WipeTransition()
    VentanaMenu:
    VentanaNuevas:
    VentanaTanda:

<VentanaMenu>:
    name: 'menu'
    AnchorLayout:
        BoxLayout:
            anchor_x: 'center'
            anchor_y: 'center'
            padding: 0,10,0,0
            spacing: 10
            size_hint:1, 0.25
            orientation: 'vertical'
            # Botones de presentación
            Button:
                id: button5
                text: "Tiempo para nuevas preguntas"
                on_release: app.root.current = 'nuevas'; app.root.get_screen('nuevas').showTUQ()
            Button:
                id: button6
                text: "Hacer tanda de preguntas"
                on_release: app.root.current = 'tanda'


<VentanaTanda>:
    name: 'tanda'
    id: tanda
    BoxLayout:
        size: root.size
        orientation: 'vertical'
        padding: 20
        spacing: 0

        #label1 muestra la pregunta
        Label:
            id: label1
            color: 1,0,1,1
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: 191/255.0, 144/255.0, 63/255.0, 1
                Rectangle:
                    size: self.size
                    pos: self.pos

        #label2 muestra la respuesta
        Label:
            id: label2
            color: 1,0,1,1
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba:  110/255.0, 191/255.0, 63/255.0, 1
                Rectangle:
                    pos:self.pos
                    size: self.size

        Label:
            id: label3
            color: 1,0,1,1
            text: str(tanda.score)
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: 74/255.0, 25/255.0, 44/255.0, 1
                Rectangle:
                    pos:self.pos
                    size: self.size


        BoxLayout:
            padding: 0,10,0,10
            spacing: 10
            size_hint:1, 0.30
            orientation: 'horizontal'
            Button:
                id: button1
                text: "Mostrar respuesta"
                on_release: tanda.showanswer()
            Button:
                id: button2
                text: "Pregunta Acertada"
                on_release: tanda.score += 10

            Button:
                id: button3
                text: "Pregunta Fallada"
                on_release: tanda.score -= 5
            Button:
                id: button4
                text: "Mostrar pregunta"
                on_release: tanda.showquestion()

        #Botón Para volver al menu
        Button:
            size_hint:1, 0.25
            text: "Volver al menu"
            on_release: app.root.current = 'menu'

<VentanaNuevas>
    name: 'nuevas'
    id: nuevas
    BoxLayout:
        size: root.size
        orientation: 'vertical'
        padding: 20
        spacing: 10

        #label4 muestra el tiempo hasta las preguntas
        Label:
            id: label4
            color: 1,0,1,1
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: 33/255.0, 127/255.0, 190/255.0, 1
                Rectangle:
                    pos:self.pos
                    size: self.size

        #Botón Para volver al menu
        Button:
            size_hint:1, 0.10
            text: "Volver al menu"
            on_release: app.root.current = 'menu'
```

He añadido dos botones que no están en tu código a las ventanas `VentanaTanda` y `VentanaNuevas` para poder volver al menú y ver el funcionamiento de `ScreenManager`.

En este caso se cambia entre las mismas instancias de las ventanas, observa que si estando en la ventana de `VentanaTanda`, vuelves al `VentanaMenu` y luego en otro momento vuelves a `VentanaTanda` la puntuación y  todo lo demás se ha mantenido.

Recuerda que puedes cambiar la [animación](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.screenmanager.html#changing-transitions) que se muestra al pasar de una ventana a otra.

Comment: Hay que cambiar la línea `on_release: tanda.showTUQ()` por `on_release: tanda.showquestion()`

Comment: Tampoco funciona el botón "Tiempo para nuevas preguntas", debería cargarse un texto en el label4 (label azul). He intentado corregirlo pero nada...podría abrir una nueva pregunta y tratar el error que me da, como prefieras...

Comment: Vale @Mr.Baldan , ahora lo arreglo. A ver si me aclaro, `Tiempo para nuevas preguntas` debe abrir la ventana a la que yo llamo `VentanaNuevas` y a la vez cargar en su Label (el azul) un texto llamando al método `showTUQ()`. Corrigeme si me equivoco.

Comment: @Mr.Baldan en un principio solo copie tu código sin dar improtancia a las funciones de los botones en si ya que la pregunta va enfocada al manejo de ventanas y tampoco tenia claro que pretendías que hiciera cada cosa. Ya lo he modificado y creo que hace lo que pretendes, de todas formas revisalo porque las modificaciones las he hecho desde el teléfono y editar código en el smartphone no es lo más cómodo del mundo :). `showTUQ` es un método de `VentanaNueva` ahora, hay más formas de hacer esto pero creo que el método debe estar en la ventana sobre la que actua por cuestion de claridad. Saludos.

Comment: Si, en principio, la pregunta iba orientada a solucionar el problema de las ventanas, sin dar importancia a los botones. Pero luego me quede con las ganas de que todo funcionara, por eso te dije que podría abrir una nueva pregunta y tratar el error que me da pero como prefierieras. Muchas gracias por haber corregido la funcionalidad de los botones y por toda la demás ayuda recibida por tus contribuciones